# Markers in a stairstep graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to set markers for data points in a stairstep graph. What I want to get is similar to what is given in [Matlab documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html):

[image]

By running this what I get is however:

[image]

So also non-data points are marked. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I get the same result as the documentation here on R2014b (Linux). What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I use R2013a on Win.

Comment: This is [the documented behavior for R2013a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/matlab/ref/stairs.html). It seems to have changed in [R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/matlab/ref/stairs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired plot in old versions, you can add markers after plotting the stairs:

```
X = linspace(0,4*pi,20);
Y = sin(X);

figure
stairs(X, Y, '--r');
hold on;
plot(X, Y, 'or');
hold off;
```

[image]